# Spark making expensive S3 API calls

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks

I have a spark job which receives a list of ~100k files and gets invoked every 10mins. These files are in s3. The paths look like:

```
s3://<bucket>/<folder>/<file_name>
```

Files are loaded like this:

```
df = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").schema(schema).parquet(*files)
```

Behind the scenes, it seems spark makes a LIST and HEAD API call for each file. This is quite wasteful as these are **files** not **directories** and are **guaranteed** to exist due to the nature of the job. Ive looked at the spark codebase and it seems, this behaviour is part of the [InMemoryFileIndex](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/InMemoryFileIndex.scala). Is there a way to configure spark to directly make the **GET** calls and skip list/head calls?

Comment: I'm not sure what [databricks] brings to the table, but I think you need to investigate getting the "s3a://' protocol working in your Spark application.

Comment: Are you sure the `mergeSchema` option does not **require** extra **I/O** to **ensure** that Spark actually **merges** the **schema** beforehand? Just **saying**...

Comment: Remember that S3 is _not_ a file system; it's an object store, you use it because it's cheap and has built-in georeplication, but you cannot expect good performance from the "connectors" that try to emulate a file system out of it. And even with HDFS, reading a bunch of small files is a recipe for disaster -- Hadoop and Spark are built for BIG data i.e. a few huge files that can be split into logical blocks.

Comment: Databricks claim that they have "optimizations" in their own S3 connector, which is then supposedly distinct from the EMR connector (`s3:`) and the Hadoop connector (`s3a:`) so... the answer might be in their documentation, since that connector is not Open Source AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is quite wasteful as these are files not directories and are guaranteed to exist due to the nature of the job.

problem here is that the filesystem layer doesn't know that "the nature of the job", so it does its own probes at times

Looks also like InMemoryFileIndex.scala is pretty inefficient; it does its own treewalk except for some hard coded bits for HDFS, and does seem to rescanning all the files its just listed again.

Yes, scope for improvement, as open source projects say. But as they also tend to say "please submit a patch"